# Multi-Dimensional Arrays Julia

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, julia

I am new to using Julia and have little experience with the language. I am trying to understand how multi-dimensional arrays work in it and how to access the array at the different dimensions. The documentation confuses me, so maybe someone here can explain it better.

I created an array (m = Array{Int64}(6,3)) and am trying to access the different parts of that array. Clearly I am understanding it wrong so any help in general about Arrays/Multi-Dimensional Arrays would help.

Thanks

**Edit** I am trying to read a file in that has the contents

```
58 129 10
58 129 7
25 56 10
24 125 25
24 125 15
13 41 10
0
```

The purpose of the project is to take these fractions (58/129) and round the fractions using farey sequence. The last number in the row is what both numbers need to be below. Currently, I am not looking for help on how to do the problem, just how to create a multidimensional array with all the numbers except the last row (0). My trouble is how to put the numbers into the array after I have created it.

So I want m[0][0] = 58, so on. I'm not sure how syntax works for this and the manual is confusing. Hopefully this is enough information.

Comment: You're going to need to be a bit more specific.  What are you trying to do?  What are you expecting?  What is different from your expectations?

Comment: Are you saying you have trouble understanding [the manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/arrays/)? Any particular part of it?

Comment: Arrays are 1-indexed; perhaps that’s a piece of the puzzle you missed? There’s a more leisurely introduction [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introducing_Julia/Arrays_and_tuples).

Comment: So even though it outputs a 6x3 array, it is 1-indexed? Hmm, I'm going to keep reading that article. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Julia's arrays are not lists-of-lists or arrays of pointers.  They are a single container, with elements arranged in a rectangular shape. As such, you do not access successive dimensions with repeated indexing calls like `m[j][i]` — instead you use one indexing call with multiple indices: `m[i, j]`.

If you trim off that last `0` in your file, you can just use the built-in `readdlm` to load that file into a matrix.  I've copied those first six rows into my clipboard to make it a bit easier to follow here:

```
julia> str = clipboard()
"58 129 10\n58 129 7\n25 56 10\n24 125 25\n24 125 15\n13 41 10"

julia> readdlm(IOBuffer(str), Int) # or readdlm("path/to/trimmed/file", Int)
6×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 58  129  10
 58  129   7
 25   56  10
 24  125  25
 24  125  15
 13   41  10
```

That's not very helpful in teaching you how Julia's arrays work, though. Constructing an array like `m = Array{Int64}(6,3)` creates an uninitialized matrix with 18 elements arranged in 6 rows and 3 columns.  It's a bit easier to see how things work if we fill it with a sensible pattern:

```
julia> m .= [10,20,30,40,50,60] .+ [1 2 3]
6×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 11  12  13
 21  22  23
 31  32  33
 41  42  43
 51  52  53
 61  62  63
```

This has set up the values of the array to have the row number in their tens place and the column number in the ones place. Accessing `m[r,c]` returns the value in `m` at row `r` and column `c`.

```
julia> m[2,3] # second row, third column
23
```

Now, `r` and `c` don't have to be integers — they can also be vectors of integers to select multiple rows or columns:

```
julia> m[[2,3,4],[1,2]] # Selects rows 2, 3, and 4 across columns 1 and 2
3×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 21  22
 31  32
 41  42
```

Of course ranges like `2:4` are just vectors themselves, so you can more easily and efficiently write that example as `m[2:4, 1:2]`.  A `:` by itself is a shorthand for a vector of all the indices within the dimension it indexes into:

```
julia> m[1, :] # the first row of all columns
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 11
 12
 13

julia> m[:, 1] # all rows of the first column
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
 11
 21
 31
 41
 51
 61
```

Finally, note that Julia's `Array` is column-major and arranged contiguously in memory. This means that if you just use one index, like `m[2]`, you're just going to walk down that first column.  As a special extension, we support what's commonly referred to as "linear indexing", where we allow that single index to span into the higher dimensions.  So `m[7]` accesses the 7th contiguous element, wrapping around into the first row of the second column:

```
julia> m[5],m[6],m[7],m[8]
(51, 61, 12, 22)
```